# Use LINQ to group data from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to use LINQ to group data from a DataTable (columns: userid, chargetag, charge).

The content could look like this:

```
userid    chargetag    charge
-----------------------------
user1     tag3         100
user2     tag3         100
user3     tag5         250
```

I need something like this as a result:

```
chargetag    count    sum
-------------------------
tag3         2        200
tag5         1        250
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("chargetag") into g
                  let count = g.Count()
                  select new
                  {
                      ChargeTag = g.Key,
                      Count = count,
                  };
```

I can extract the name of the chargetag and the number of it.
How would I have to change the LINQ query to access the sum of charges as well?

Thanks in advance :-)

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's pretty easy - just use the `Sum` extension method on the group.

```
var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("chargetag") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      ChargeTag = g.Key,
                      Count = g.Count(),
                      ChargeSum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("charge"))
                  };
```

(I've removed the `let` clause here as it wasn't really buying you anything.)

Now that *may* be inefficient; it may end up grouping twice in order to perform two aggregation operations. You *could* fix that like with a query continuation like this, if you really wanted:

```
var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("chargetag") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      ChargeTag = g.Key,
                      List = g.ToList(),
                  } into g
                  select new 
                  {
                      g.ChargeTag,
                      Count = g.List.Count,
                      ChargeSum = g.List.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("charge"))
                  };
```

Or with a `let` clause instead:

```
var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("chargetag") into g
                  let list = g.ToList()
                  select new
                  {
                      ChargeTag = g.Key,
                      Count = list.Count,
                      ChargeSum = list.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("charge"))
                  };
```

Comment: Nice explanation (as usual). I'd be interested to know if the first option actually groups twice or if it gets optimised.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: What's a good way for me to grasp all this LINQ stuff? I've got your `C# In Depth` book, but I get lost in the LINQ section (like your example above). The rest of the coding stuff isn't too bad.

Comment: @jp2code: Well, there are various books *just* about LINQ... or you might like my Edulinq blog series: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Comment: Can someone give me the code in VB? I tried the converters online but I get an error "'Into' expected".

Comment: @RookieAppler: Rather than try converters, I suggest you read the documentation for grouping with LINQ in VB - then if you're still having problems, ask a new question with details of what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.