# Using Linq to GroupBy and Sum datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, sum

**Hi, I have a Datatable like this:**

```
Id             Amount 1        Amount 2        Amount 3  
1              2               2               2  
12             4               6               4  
12             6               6               5  
22             7               2               1  
22             7               2               2
```

**I need to get my datatable like this:**

```
Id             Amount 1        Amount 2        Amount 3  
1              2               2               2  
12             10              12              9    
22             14              4               3
```

I originally tried to do it in an anonymous method but I need to return it to another class which cannot be done with anonymous method.
My second attempt was to do this so it can be returned:

```
DataTable ddt = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Sum(g => g.Field<int>("Amount 1"))
        .GroupBy(g => new { Col1 = g["ID"] })
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["ID"]).First())
        .CopyToDataTable();
```

This code definitely wont compile but Any help/advice if possible would be really appreciated. I'm very new to linq.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use LINQ to group data from DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829129/use-linq-to-group-data-from-datatable)

Comment: google can be your best friend if used properly

Comment: You need to do the group by first, then in your select you'd do each sum.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` first, then project the groups to `DataRow`s, then create the `DataTable` using `CopyToDataTable` extension:

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                  var row = dt.NewRow();

                  row["Id"] = g.Key;
                  row["Amount 1"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount 1"));
                  row["Amount 2"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount 2"));
                  row["Amount 3"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount 3"));

                  return row;
              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Hi, I used this code but it empties the dt table and only keeps the line added ?!

Comment: Hello this solution work on Android and also windows build but when i build for iOS it throw Not Supported Exception as in this question.[System.Data throws NotSupportedException on iOS Unity Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389253/system-data-throws-notsupportedexception-on-ios-unity-build?noredirect=1#comment110343781_62389253) Could you give and answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

You are making your calls out of order. The code below wont put the data into a table, but it will give you data you could put into a table easily.

```
dt.AsEnumberable()
    .GroupBy(g => g["ID])
    .Select(g => new {
        Id = g.Key, 
        Amount1 = g.Sum(s => s.Amount1), 
        Amount2 = g.Sum(s => s.Amount2), 
        Amount3 = g.Sum(s => s.Amount3)});
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. A slight Change to Arturo's code to help with cast issues if you have decimal values and use a datatable as a datatable not a variable. (Note that r[15] is the column you will be summing)

```
                  dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => r["fldReportCode"])
                    .Select(g =>
                     {
                        var row = dt.NewRow();

                      row["fldReportCode"] = g.Key;
                      row[15] = g.Sum(r => (decimal)r[15]);
                      //row["Amount 2"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount 2"));
                      //row["Amount 3"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount 3"));

                          return row;
                      }).CopyToDataTable();
```