# LINQ on datatable, group, sum and get comma delimited string C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable that is currently of the structure

```
Index | Player | Score
a     |  abby  |   1
z     |  bob   |   5
f     |  abby  |   4
p     |  bob   |   3
```

I want to group the datatable by player in Linq such that it will provide the index column as a comma-separated string, and sum the score column for that player returning the result as a datatable.

For example the above should end up like.

```
Index | Player | Score
a,f   |  abby  |   5   
z,p   |  bob   |   8
```

I have unfortunately no clue how to do this, I can only find examples on how to do the sum component, but some of these only seem to work on a `datatable` with two columns and not three.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to work with a datatable with two columns and sum, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575198/using-linq-to-groupby-and-sum-datatable) but I am not sure how to do the comma separated string part

Comment: just use lambda that takes first string, adds comma and adds second string

Comment: use string.join for comma separated part. See my answer below with complete query @user44775

Answer (score 4):

You can simple get it using this query:

-Using `string.Join()` - get flattened array with indexes for each user

-Using `GroupBy()` - get group by player name

-Using `Sum()` - get sum score for each player

```
var data = new[]
    {
      new Foo {Index = "a", Player = "abby", Score = 1},
      new Foo {Index = "z", Player = "bob", Score = 5},
      new Foo {Index = "f", Player = "abby", Score = 4},
      new Foo {Index = "p", Player = "bob", Score = 3},
    };

var result = data.GroupBy(l => l.Player)
             .Select(cl => new Foo()
             {
                Index = string.Join(", ", data.Where(d => d.Player == cl.Key).Select(d => d.Index).ToArray()),
                Player = cl.Key,
                Score = cl.Sum(c => c.Score)
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var groupedData = ctx.TableName.GroupBy(x => x.Player).Select(x => new TableName
{
    Player = x.Key,
    Score = x.Sum(y => y.Score),
    Index = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Index).ToArray())
});
```

Comment: Even if the answer is correct, please refrain from posting code only answers. Try to explain why and how the code solves the problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

Should  get you closer:

```
var results = from game in PlayersGames
    group game by game.Player into group
    select new { Player = group.Key, TotalScore = group.Sum(g => g.Score), Indexes = String.Join(",", group.Select(g => g.Index)) };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must group by `Player`. Then, you have just to select the new fields using `String.Join` for the indexes and `Sum` for the scores:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Player"))
    .Select(y=> new { 
                Index=String.Join(",", y.Select(z => z.Field<string>("Index"))),
                Player=y.Key,
                Score=y.Sum(sc=>sc.Field<int>("Score")) 
                }
            );
```

**Edit**

I've just seen you wanted the result as a DataTable. You can do something like this:

```
DataTable dtResult=dtOriginal.Clone();
dtOriginal.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Player"))
           .Select(y=> new {  
                            Index=String.Join(",", y.Select(z => z.Field<string>("Index"))),
                            Player=y.Key, 
                            Score=y.Sum(sc=>sc.Field<int>("Score"))
                            })
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(i => {dtResult.Rows.Add(i.Index, i.Player, i.Score);});
```

Is mostly the same as all the answers here. We just copy the results to a list, and then add the rows with a `ForEach`. Have in mind that there must be lots of ways to do the same.

Comment: After you've groupped by instance it becomes `Queryable` and `string.Join()` can't be used for that case

Comment: @LabLab Wrong. I `String.Join` a `Select` result, so this works  `Index=String.Join(",", y.Select(z => z.Field<string>("Index")))`. You can try this yourself