# C# Linq Datatable groupby datetime month

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a datatable that looks like this

[image]

The output I'm trying to achieve is described in the picture, where I want to group by the month of the datetime, and agent I suppose. This is what I have so far.

```
            DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Agent", typeof(string));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            dtTemp = dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => r[0])
           .Select(g =>
           {
               var row = dt.NewRow();

               row[0] = g.Key;
               row[1] = g.Sum(r => (decimal)r[1]);

               return row;
           })
           .CopyToDataTable();
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .GroupBy(r => new {agent = r[0], month = new DateTime(r[2].Year, r[2].Month, 1)})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From analyzing your post, you need to group by data table rows by column `Agent` and only month and year from column `Date`.

You need to take one temporary data table `dt` that can hold data type for each column in your resultant data table `result`.

So `CopyToDataTable()` will copy all of your `dtTemp` group data to new `result` data table with temporary `dt` columns data type.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Agent", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));


DataTable result = dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(x => new
     {
         Agent = x.Field<string>("Agent"),
         Amount = x.Field<decimal>("Amount"),
         Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("MM-yyyy")
     })
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Agent, x.Date })
     .Select(g =>
     {
         var r = dt.NewRow();

         r["Agent"] = g.Key.Agent;
         r["Amount"] = g.Sum(c => c.Amount);
         r["Date"] = g.FirstOrDefault().Date;

         return r;
     })
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = dtTemp.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(grp => new { grpmonth = Convert.ToDateTime(grp["Date"]).Month, grpyear = Convert.ToDateTime(grp["Date"]).Year, grpagent = grp["Agent"] })
                                 .Select(val =>
                                     {
                                         var row = dtTemp.NewRow();

                                         row["Agent"] = val.FirstOrDefault()["Agent"];
                                         row["Amount"] = val.Sum(amt => Convert.ToDecimal(amt["Amount"]));
                                         row["Date"] = val.FirstOrDefault()["Date"];
                                         return row;
                                     }
                                     )
                                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575504/11186543)

Answer (score 0):

So from your input sequence, you want all used `Agents`, with the total sum of the `Amounts` per month.

Let's assume your DataTable is a sequence of Rows, and that it easily can be converted to a sequence of Rows:

```
class RowData
{
    public string Agent {get; set}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int Amount {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<RowData> tableData = ...
```

The solution if your problem is to make groups of RowData with equal value for Agent, and to group these groups again to make subgroups with equal value for year and month

```
var AgentsWithAmountsPerMonth = tableData
    .GroupBy(row => row.Agent,        // make groups of rows with same Agent

    // ResultSelector: get the Agent (=key), with all rows that have this Agent
    (agent, rowsWithThisAgent) => new
    {
        Agent = agent,

        // to calculate the totals per year/month, extract the year / month / amount
        TotalsPerMonth = rowsWithThisAgent.Select(row => new
        {
            Year = row.Date.Year,
            Month = row.Date.Month,
            Amount = row.Amount,
        })

        // and group by same Year / Month:
        .GroupBy(row => new {row.Year, row.Month},

            // ResultSelector
            (yearMonth, rowsWithThisYearMonth) => new
            {
                Year = yearMonth.Year,
                Month = yearMonth.Month,
                Total = rowsWithThisYearMont.Select(row => row.Amount).Sum(),

                // Or put the year and month in one field:
                Month = new DateTime(yearMonth.Year, yearMonth.Month, 1),
            },
    });



    });
```