# How to select a column after GroupBy in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In the beginning i had a DataTable that contained two columns, i needed to GroupBy with column "TasksId" and get the sum of column "Quantity" that has the same "TaskId". I've sucessfully achieved that with this post ([Use LINQ to group data from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829129/use-linq-to-group-data-from-datatable)), but now, the DataTable contains more columns and i need to retrieve all of them after the groupBy, how can i achieve that?

I tried to use GroupBy multiple columns in LINQ, but i didn't understand how exactly works and how i can use that with the sum of "Quantity" column.

```
var groupedData = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
                                      group b by b.Field<string>("TasksId") into g
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          TaskId= g.Key,
                                          Count= g.Count(),
                                          Sum= g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Quantity"))
                                      };
```

Right now i'm getting the TaskId and the sum of "Quantity" fields with the same TaskId, what i want to retrieve now is multiple columns values and still get the sum of column "Quantity".

Comment: When you run an aggregate query (e.g. by using `Sum()`), you cannot access any columns that are not in the `group by` section. If they're not part of the `group by` then they could be different on every row.

Comment: Note that `g` is `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. It gives access to all full rows in the grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be wise to separate your concerns more (See [Separation of concerns demystified](https://blog.ndepend.com/separation-of-concerns-explained/))

You should separate your tables from the way they are converted. This way you'll have two table classes and one function to convert a sequence of one type or table rows into another type of table rows.

This has the advantage, that if later you decide to store your data differently, for instance in a database, or a CSV file, your conversion, nor your other tables will have to change. This will also be the case if you decide to change the way you visualize the table to an operator, for instance from a table into a graph.

I don't know what tables you have. It seems you have a table with `Tasks`, and another table, let's call it a table with `Destinations`

To represent the rows in your tables, you'll need two classes:

```
class Task
{
    public int TaskId {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Destination
{
    public int TaskId {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Furthermore you'll need two classes that represent your tables. If you want to hide that this version is in fact a DataTable, your class should aggregate a DataTable: *it has a DataTable*, instead of *it is a DataTable*. This way you'll be free to change your DataTable into a database table, or a CSV file, or a DataGridView in a WinForms application.

Anyway, your table needs to implement IEnumerable:

```
// Class Tasks represents a "table" of Tasks
class Tasks : IEnumerable<Task>, IEnumerable
{
    // create at construction. It has the columns of a Task:
    private readonly DataTable dataTable;

    public Tasks()
    {
        // create an empty DataTable
    }
    public Tasks(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
    {
        // creates a DataTable filled with the tasks
    }

    // only if you sometimes still need the fact that this is internally still a DataTable
    public DataTable DataTable {get;} => this.DataTable;
}
```

You know DataTables better than I do, and you know what you want to do with your datatables. You'll know better than I whether you need to have functions like Add / Delete / Find. Consider implementing `ICollection<Task>` or `IList<Task>` instead of `IEnumerable<Task>`

To help you the implementation of IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetTasks().GetEnumerator();
}
IEnumerator IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}

private IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    return this.dataTable.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(row => new Task
       {
           TaskId = row.Field<int>("TaskId"),
           Quantity = row.Field<int>("Quantity"),
           ...
       });
}
```

Don't do a `ToList()`! If your caller only wants a few Rows, it would be a waste to convert all rows. Let your caller do `Take(4).ToList();` or whatever number of rows he wants.

If you want to implement `ICollection<Task>` you'll also have to implement functions like `Add`, `Remove`, `Count`. They will be fairly easy, use the `DataTable.Rows` for this. That class already implements `ICollection`, so you'll only have to convert your items to and from `Task`

```
public void Add(Task task)
{
    DataRow rowToAdd = new DataRow();
    // fill the datarow with the values from Task
    this.dataTable.Rows.add(rowToAdd);
}
```

Now that you've got your `Tasks` class, your `Destinations` class will be very similar.

Now the only thing you need to do is to convert a sequence of `Tasks` into a sequence of `Destinations`.

To make this look very similar to LINQ I'll write it as an extension method. See [extension methods demystified](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<Destination> ToDestinations(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    // make groups of tasks with same TaskId
    return tasks.GroupBy(task => task.TaskId,

       // from every found taskId, with all found Tasks with this taskId,
       // make one new Destination object
       (taskId, tasksWithThisTaskId) => new Destination
       {
            TaskId = taskId,
            Count = tasksWithThisTaskId.Count(),   // for Count: count all Tasks in this group
            TotalQuantity = tasksWithThisTaskId  // for TotalQuanty:
                 .Select(task => task.Quantity)  // extract the quantities of all tasks
                 .Sum(),                         // and Sum them

            ... // other destination properties, use either taskId, or the
                // tasks with this taskId
    }
```

Usage:

```
// suppose you have a sequence of tasks:
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = ...
// put it in a Tasks object, so you have a DataTable:
Tasks tasks = new Tasks(tasks);

// if desired we can add a new Task (=Row) to the table:
Task taskToAdd = new Task {...};
tasks.Add(taskToAdd);

// convert to Destinations:
Destinations destinations = tasks.ToDestinations();   // yes, only one line!

// do you need the DataTable?
DataTable destinationsTable = destinations.DataTable; // yes, also only one line!
```

Because you separated the concerns, you'll only need little changes if you decide to add or remove a column in your Tasks, or if you decide that your Destinations is internally a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Update your group by to take multiple fields. The below should be close:

```
var groupedData = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by new 
                  {
                     b.Field<string>("TasksId"), 
                     b.Field<string>("Another Column")
                  } into g
                  select new
                  {
                      TaskId= g.Key,
                      Count= g.Count(),
                      Sum= g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Quantity"))
                  };
```